# Setting a button's text through script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in my html that I append. How do I set said button's text to "Click Me"? I've scoured every corner of Stack Overflow and to no avail.

```
var button = container.appendChild(document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("id", button);
```

Here's what I've already tried:

```
button.text="Click Me"
button.innerHTML="Click Me";
button.value="Click Me";
button.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Click Me";
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `innerHTML` or `innerText` should have worked.

Comment: Not exactly related, but `button.setAttribute("id", button);` probably doesn't do what you expect. Maybe you should wrap `button` in the argument list into quotes. Currently the id is `[object HTMLButtonElement]`.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the `var button =` line, so the button isn't created. After fixing the typo, it works with `button.innerHTML`. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qsk8ahej/1/

Comment: did you notice syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing parenthesis:

.appendChild( ... )

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var button = container.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));

button.innerHTML="Click Me!!";
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```